# How do I access crash reports instead of .ips.beta files for a TestFlight Beta-distributed app from device in Xcode 6.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, testflight

In previous versions of Xcode 6.x, if I wanted to access crash reports, I would go to Window > Devices, select the device, and hit "view device logs". However, when I do this now, crashes I've just hit are not showing up in this window (I cleared out any previous logs to make sure they weren't simply showing up in an unexpected place in the list):

[image: you cannot has logs]

When I have the device sync with iTunes (and *ONLY* when I have it sync), it pulls the log off as `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/[device name]/[app name]_[timestamp]_iPhone.ips.beta`. Looking at older crash reports, they just end in `.ips` instead of `.ips.beta`.

When I drag the `.ips.beta` into the Console app, it appears that it's the crash log, but with a bunch of JSON at the top. I have verified that the phone I'm using has sending of crash reports to developers on so that I would theoretically be able to use the TestFlight crash reporting, but from what I can tell it [takes at least a day](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-crashes_organizer/AboutCrashesOrganizer/AboutCrashesOrganizer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015147-CH1-SW1) to have crashes show up in the Crashes tab of the organizer. This isn't terribly helpful when trying to debug an issue found by a non-developer.

Note: We're using Crashlytics in the app, and crashes do seem to be showing up on Fabric, but previously that didn't cause any issues for actually getting the logs off the device. In theory, having an exception listener shouldn't completely eat crash logs for breakfast.

Is there any way to get the standard crash reports so I can just pull them off the phone if I'm using TestFlight Neue's beta program? Or if I'm going to be having non-developers do testing, do I need to be giving them signed apps if I want to be able to get quick crash reports off of them?

And yes, I have tried turning it off and on again - rebooting neither the phone nor Xcode does me any good.

Comment: I have found crashes in Organizer. There you can choose your project or Crashes (There is a top button). There, you can choose your compilation version and a list of crashes appears. Then, you can go to finder (right click). I don't know if It's what you need but I hope It helps to you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely seeing that section, but I'm not seeing any crash reports over 24h later. Bleh.

Comment: I got the same problem. I cannot even drag&drop `.ips.beta` file into Device's crash log list. :(

Comment: @samthui7 how you decided your problem?

Comment: same issue here

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first line, and add extension `.crash` - this lets you open in Xcode and get a symbolicated backtrace